# Проблема работы туннеля

Tags: python-3.x, http, tcp, tunnel

Решил написать сам протокол туннелирования работающий с IP.
И тут вышла такая проблема хоть и ping аж 65507(максимально большой пакет) байт работает нормально и стабильно, не работает нормально HTTP и вроде бы весь TCP. И еще это зависит от размера страницы, как это исправить
Код отвечающий за пересылку пакетов:

```
mtu = tun.mtu #1400
#где tun это виртуальное сетевое устройство, sock - TCP сокет
def writen() :
    while 1 :
        buf = tun.read(mtu)
        sock.send(buf)   
def readn() :
        while 1 :
                buf = sock.recv(mtu)
                tun.write(buf)
```

Wireshark:
 1. Запрос http:
   [image: HTTP запрос]

2. Ответ http(wireshark не распознает как HTTP):
   [image: HTTP Ответ]

Comment: Mss не подстраивается

Comment: можешь помочь и как мне это сделать???